# Can you create an inverting function using only 2-input AND ports?

Tags: math, boolean-logic, circuit

If yes, show how it can be done. If not, explain why not

Wondering if it can be done or not, and the reason why it does/doesn't work/can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. `{ AND, NOT }` is a [functional complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness) set. If you can create a NOT gate from only AND then you just need `{ AND }` to create all logic functions which is simply not true

With AND you can only clear the input (a AND 0) or create the same output from input (a AND 1, a AND a). Nothing else

Comment: Is there an easy way to spot that it would'nt work by only viewing the 'Truth table' of AND tho?

Comment: @DPD yes, as I said from the truth table you'll see that with AND you can only get 0 or the original bit. You have 3 kinds of input to feed into each pin: 0, 1 and a so you'll have 6 different inputs. None of them will give you `NOT a`